# How to create Geofences on Android?

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am trying to figure out how to create Geofences on Android. I've followed several tutorials out there, but I can never get it to work for me.

The idea is, I want to create a Geofence and then display it on the map using Google Maps. Then when a user enters the geofence area, it will show notification and also do something.

The only requirement I want for creating Geofences is if the user is in that specific location. Let's say he is in a local Starbucks in Downtown Seattle. He can only create a Geofence if he is in that particular area.

All I want to know is how can I achieve this first step in creating a Geofence? Even if it means having to re-write a lot of code. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

```
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence");
    Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
    addGeofence(geofencingRequest);
}

private static final long GEOFENCE_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 100.0f;

private Geofence createGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius) {

    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
            .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_DURATION)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build();


}

private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {

    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build();
}

private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (geofencePendingIntent != null)
        return geofencePendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    if (checkPermissions())
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, request,
            createGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback((ResultCallback<? super Status>) this);
}

public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess() ) {
        drawGeofence();
    }
    else {

    }
}

private LatLng latLng;
private Circle geofenceLimit;
private void drawGeofence() {
    if (geofenceLimit != null){
        geofenceLimit.remove();
    }

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
            .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
            .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
    geofenceLimit = googleMap.addCircle( circleOptions );

}
```

Comment: Did you try this https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html ? What problems did you face only doing this part?
"The idea is, I want to create a Geofence and then display it on the map using Google Maps. Then when a user enters the geofence area, it will show notification and also do something." I would recommend divide your problem into smaller parts, like first make goefencing work that you get a callback when user enter a geofence. When that works than try to show it on a Map.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that documentation. I have to be honest, I'm confused with the documentation (Sorry, I'm still quite new to Android programming). Just to make sure I'm on the right track. Is this how to properly call the location API?

    private GeofencingClient mGeofenceClient;

    public void setmGeofenceClient(GeofencingClient mGeofenceClient) {
        this.mGeofenceClient = mGeofenceClient;
        mGeofenceClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);


    }

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing you can run this sample, and after that you can reuse code from sample to make it work for you.